# jQuery variable named radio buttons can't display message

Tags: jquery, radio-button, show-hide

I have a DIV #Message_PHPVARABLE that ought to appear at the bottom of a post when a radio button assigned to this post is selected. What happens however, is that it works fine for Post_1 but when I select an option for Post_2, the option for Post_1 is changed and Message_1 displays the new selection instead of having the Post_2 selection appear in Message_2... any help? The option the radio buttons give is Like and Dislike.

```
$data = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM Test");
$counter = 1;

while($row = mysql_fetch_array( $data )){
?>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $("input[name*='like_<?php $counter; ?>']").click(function() {
            var defaultValue = $("label[for*='" + this.id + "']").html();
            var defaultm = "You have chosen : ";
            $('#Message_<?php $counter; ?>').html('').html(defaultm + defaultValue + ' | Value is : ' + $(this).val());
        });

    });
</script>

<div id="post_<?php $counter; ?>" class="post">
    <b><?php echo $row['Title']; ?></b><br>
    Expires: <?php echo $row['Exp']; ?><br>
<ul id="listM"></ul>
<div class="left"><p><input id="like_<?php $counter; ?>" type="radio" name="like_<?php $counter; ?>" value="1" />
<label for="like_<?php $counter; ?>">Like</label></p></div>
<div class="right"><p><input id="dislike_<?php $counter; ?>" type="radio" name="like_<?php $counter; ?>" value="0" />
<label for="dislike_<?php $counter; ?>">Dislike</label></p></div>
<hr />
</div>
<div id="Message_<?php $counter; ?>"></div>

<?php 
$counter += 1;
} 
?>
```

If I hard code everything (removing the $counter) then it works fine but obviously, with an infinite number of potential rows in the MySQL to be displayed, I must use variables...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a problem with your PHP (unless you typed your post incorrectly)

In order to print out `$counter` you need to `echo` it. Just typing `<?php $counter; ?>` will not put the value into your HTML. You need to use `<?php echo $counter;?>` or `<?=$counter;?>` as a shortcut.

Comment: WOW, what an amateurish mistake!